# lattices and torsion-free sublattices.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

I have the following statement that I cant proof, which according to my book is trivial.
Let $N$ be a lattice.

Let $N_1 \subset N$ be a sublattice such that $N/N_1$ is torsion-free. Then it followes that there exist a sublattice $N_2 \subset N$ s.t $N=N_1 \oplus N_2$.
some kind of rigorous explanation or proof would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What definition of "lattice" are you using here? A free abelian subgroup of $\;\Bbb R^n\;$ which contains a basis of $\;\Bbb R^n_{\Bbb R}\;$ ?

Comment: If $N/N_1$ is torsion free, then it is free, that is it has a basis. Choose elements of $N$ that maps to this basis and take $N_2$ the lattice spanned by these elements.